# Want different lookup parameters in django login

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I am using django and have email verification feature so when someone verifiy email , I activate his/her account by setting status. If some one will someone else email address then he will not be able to verify and will not able to login with that. So I was expecting django to look at status of user also while login as this status field is in table that is of django auth app.  While on login django tries to login with only username param. So on login it says:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /accounts/login/
 get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {'username': u'kaasib122@gmail.com'}
```

Is there a way to add status field also in lookup? Is there something in cofiguration for that or I need to write some sort of login backend for that? Or should I write my own view for login table in some different way? What is recommended way? Also I am thinking to let user either login using email or username in username field. So what is recommended way?

Comment: Letting two users create accounts with the same email address, even if the first one hasn't been confirmed, is a bad idea. What if both of the accounts end up being confirmed?

Comment: @DavidRobinson email address will be of one person then how can both be confirmed once one will confirm then other will not be able to confirm even

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an authentication backend that suits your needs. Check out the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend).

Basically, you will need to write an "authenticate" method which will use "status" in the filter parameters. For using email or username, you could basically filter on one field (username or email) and if no User objects are returned for that field, filter on the other. Or you can get the user in a single filter by ORing those fields. Here's a pseudocode:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username, status=True)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username, status=True)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        # check password too
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None
```

Note that when you write new authentication backend, you need to add it to  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS parameter in your settings.py for it to be used. If you don't need the default one Django provides because you have customized it, just override that parameter, no need to add to the tuple.

Comment: will that backend override default backend and my view will use this backend automatically or I will need to write my own view code also for getting this backedn called?

Comment: where I need to place this backend and how to call that?